# iPhone User Interface steps online demo

Tags: iphone, user-interface, demo, mockups

I've designed the User Interface of an iPhone app and I wish to show an online demo of that consisting for the moment of a series of static images representing the main steps of the app.

According to you what is the best way to do this simulation? 
You know, something like a series of single webpage, optimized for mobile, containing a single image linking to the next step, but I was wondering if exists a much elegant and sophisticated solution, with a transition effect for example or other features.

I hope I was clear enough :)

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for Briefs [Briefs App Website](http://giveabrief.com/). This pretty much allows you to create an interface and step through it as if it were an application. I believe you'll need to have a developer account to run the app that will read the brief on your phone (since it wasn't able to be released in the app store).

Comment: thank you for the answer. you can vote for my question if you believe.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to static images would be to make a video.  I use the iShowU video screen capture tool and set it to record the iPhone/iPad simulator window.  I then run through the screens, type inputs, etc.  In addition to recording the video, the program records my voice as I narrate the app's features.

As to transition effects, the video will capture whatever transition animations are in your program.

In the end you have a video that you could give your user, put on YouTube, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily and for free on [AppDemoStore](http://www.appdemostore.com). You just have to upload the app screenshots and then add hotspots which are used for the navigation through the demo. 
AppDemoStore offers also the sophisticated features you are asking for:

- iPhone specific transition effects such as slide up/down/left/right, fade and flip
- gestures icons for the hotspots
- text boxes and callouts
- multiple hotspots on a screen in order to create a simulation of the app (and not just a linear demo)

Here's a sample demo: http://www.appdemostore.com/demo?id=1699008

Moreover, the demos created on AppDemoStore run in any browser and mobile device and can be embedded in your webpage or blog (like you do it with a YouTube video). With the FREE account, you can create up to 10 demos with unlimited screenshots and all the features specified above.

Regards,
Daniel